# Mockito Unit Test main function in a class

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I am fairly new to `Mockito`. I am not sure how to test the void function `emitcount()` or to actually test the class to 100%?

```
public class Class A {

    private static final String APP_NAME = "App name";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        String root = "root"
        String domain = ".com"

        Injector injector = createInjector(
                new ClassB(root, domain)
        );

        ClassC c=injector.getInstance(ClassC.class);
        c.start();

    }
}
```

Is there a way Mockito helps to cover this code to 100%?

My thoughts:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class testclass {
 @Test
    public void test() throws Throwable {

        ClassB b = new ClassB(root, domain));
        assertNotNull(b);
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(b);

        ClassC c= injector.getInstance(Class C.class);
         c.start()     

    }
}
```

Questions

1) Do I have to use `PowerMock` to test the code inside main function?

2) Does `Mockito` provide something so that all the code is covered?

3) Do I have to use `spy()`? The tricky part is creating an object 
   from injector

Comment: Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how to...actually test the class to 100%?

The solution here is to stop thinking about meaningless KPI like "test to 100%" (100% code coverage). Even hard core TDD advocates like Kent Beck will stop testing at the level where they are confident in the correctness of what they have written.

> Do I have to use PowerMock to test the code inside main function?

No.

> Does Mockito provide something so that all the code is covered?

Mockito is a mocking framework. It's not a code coverage tool. These are a separate knowledge domain.

> Do I have to use spy()? The tricky part is creating an object from injector.

Since you are learning how to test and how to use Mockito, start with simple examples and work your way up.

Because we are doing OOP, the essence is to divide our work into single responsibility objects and test the collaboration between these. In doing this, collaborators that are dependencies are passed in the constructor for the system under test (SUT). When you test, you pass in mocked versions of the dependencies into SUT and stub behaviours in order to exercise its functionality. This is what Mockito does.

Study this and become proficient at it. Then after a while, you will notice that there are some classes for which it is not easy to pass in mocks. Sometimes this is because of bad design of your classes. Sometimes, it is simply a difficulty in the framework itself.

The entry point for your app is the latter - there is a `void main(String args [])` method in which dependencies are instantiated using the `new` keyword and and then started. There is very little to be gained by aiming for 100% test coverage of this class so a pragmatic approach is simply not to test it.

Comment: Reads like the answer I would have written ... if I wouldn't have been to tired and lazy yesterday ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat thanks :-)